# How do i solve error code 5 on google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Development server on Chrome is suddenly not working. It shows error code 5. Here is a [screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f643.png)

I tried clearing the cache, restarting the system but nothing worked. Please if anyone has any solution please help

Comment: error 5 shows that something wrong with SSL on serverside, but as I see you connect to default 3000 port, so it should be plain http, change your url from https:// to http://, theoretically it should help.